# Why is ListBoxItem not getting highlighted when mousing over?

Tags: wpf, listbox, themes, mousehover

I have defined the following ListBox and am using the ShinyRed themes found [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962).  However, I'm finding that row color only changes on mouse hover if I'm hovering over the label's text.  I'd like to get the row to change color if I'm anywhere on the list item's line.  How do I fix this?

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Label Content={Binding DisplayName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` to make the items stretch.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

(Also if it still only reacts to the text try setting the `Label.Background` to `Transparent` which hit-tests. And if it *still* don't work the `ListBoxItem` control template of that theme is kinda whack)

Comment: Neither of those ideas work.  If I put in the ItemContainerStyle in, the items are completely white--I can't even see the text until I hover over it.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @bsh152s: Oh right, you'll need [`BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) because of the theme which otherwise is overidden.